# PHP shorthand if else condition issue

Tags: php, if-statement

I can't understand what is wrong I am doing with this if else shorthand code

```
$item  = '<li '. ($avatar_size > 50) ? .'style="overflow:hidden">';
```

I only want to check if condition true than add inline style else nothing.

Edit:
Of course in above statement it will remove `>` too when condition is false so I tried other statement but none of working. I am sure I must doing stupid mistake but can't figure it out.

```
$item  = '<li '. ($avatar_size > 50) ? .'style="overflow:hidden"'.:. '' .'>';
```

Comment: $item = condition is true ? do if true : do if false ;

Comment: You mean I can't use while assigning to variable?

Comment: do you want <li '. (($avatar_size > 50) ? '' : 'style="overflow:hieend">');

Comment: thanks everyone to vote me down. :) I never mind because I am learning and that is more important for me than down vote :) by the way @deceze help me and solve the issue and learn new tihng. Thank to him and you all too

Comment: @farmer1992 actually I have realized and edited the question that if I will use statement like that than closing `>` will be removed. thanks a lot

Comment: I wonder what your CSS overflow value should do? `hieend` is not on the list of defined values, see yourself: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/overflow Probably you meant `hidden`.

Comment: It was typing mistake and sure it's for `hidden`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no "shorthand if", `?:` is an *operator* and it *always* must consist of `?` *and* `:`. The best you can do with this is:

```
$item  = '<li' . ($avatar_size > 50 ? ' style="overflow:hidden"' : null) . '>';
```

Comment: `null` is not the best empty string I can think of. What about `""`?

Comment: @Sven this means instead of using null better way is "" ?

Comment: @Sven I simply try to avoid string literals whenever possible. It may or may not be better to use `''` here, I find constants preferable to strings and `null` signifies "no value", so I don't see a problem with it. Since `null` casts to an empty string there's no difference really.

Comment: Actually there is a value needed: An empty string is the best choice in this context. NULL may be better in a different case.

Answer (score 2):

I have a late answer with more explanation, although the initial one is right.

**About the ternary operator**

```
$expression ? $value1 : $value2
```

The ternary operator works like a function, e.g. it returns a value.

Which value? That's where the first parameter comes into play. It is an expression that is evaluated either to `true` or `false`.

If it is true, the second parameter is returned as a value. If it is false, the third parameter is returned.

Since you are dealing with strings on the outside, the returned value will be used as a string. It is a very good idea to only return string values then and not confuse the reader of your code with returning NULL. It would be converted to an empty string nonetheless.

**Shortcut ternary operator**

```
$expression ?: $value
```

This one omits the second value for true, and returns $expression if this evaluates to true, or $value otherwise. This works great for checking whether a variable has been defined and set to a value (other than those that evaluate to false), and use a default value otherwise.

By reversing an expression is is possible to omit a parameter, but it is not possible to return an empty string or something else in your case.

```
$avatar_size <= 50 ?: ' style="overflow:hidden"'
```

This does not work because if the avatar size is below 50, a "true" would be returned and be used inside the string - which converts to `"1"`.